# Disable Access to USB storage on Android

Tags: android, usb

My Android tablet is being passed around some clients of mine, and due to confidentiality, I cannot allow the different companies to access each others files.

As such, I have created different user accounts on the tablet (Android 8.1), one for each company. Their access is limited, and as such they cannot access the built-in File Manager.

But how do I make sure they cannot simply plug the tablet to a PC and access all files through the mass storage? Preferably, they shouldn't be able to access anything stored on the phone.

The tablet isn't rooted.

I'm desperate for a solution. I have looked into disabling the USB port ([Link 1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/104096/security-how-to-prevent-usb-mounting-of-mobile-device), [Link 2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/general/disabling-usb-security-t2180404)) without luck. Using multiple tablets is not an option either, as each client isn't allowed to look at their own files (for protection of IP). Please advice.

Comment: Try to follow this answer, I hope this help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968293/9686651

Comment: Without rooting that tablet, I do not think there is a whole lot you can do to disable the usb port, short of hacking the hardware.

Comment: Rooting the device really isn't ideal. Instead of disabling the USB port, isn't there a way to e.g. tie a specific folder to each account? Or having the USB port defaulting to charging only, and then disable the option to switch to File Transfer.

The data file that is stored on the tablet is generated from an app I have developed. I need access to this data after the clients have used the tablet.